# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key <x>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a page with two DropDownLists and two TextFields. Both DropDownLists are populated from mySQl database tables using ADO.Net Entity Model in Microsoft Visual Studio 2015.
**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ViewResult MngBranch()
    {
        DbModel pdb = new DbModel();
        ViewBag.type = new SelectList(pdb.branchtypes, "Id", "Type");
        ViewBag.name = new SelectList(pdb.companies, "IdCompany", "CompanyName");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ViewResult MngBranch(Branch branch)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ViewBag.Name = branch.BranchName;
            return View("BranchSaved");
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        <p>Company Name: @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyName, (SelectList)ViewBag.name,"Choose an option")</p>
        <p>Branch Name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BranchName)</p>
        <p>Branch Code: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BranchCode)</p>
        <p>Branch Type:@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BranchType, (SelectList)ViewBag.type, "Choose an option")
        </p>
```

For some reason in this particular view I get the error:

**There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable`<SelectListItem>` ' that has the key 'CompanyName'.**

when validation fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty straightforward. You are using `ViewData` instead of the view model. So you cannot possibly expect to be able to use strongly typed helpers such as `Html.DropDownListFor` in your views. You should rather create an instance of your view model in the controller action that will be passed to the view.

So as always start by writing a proper view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string BranchType { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchCode { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CompanyNames { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BranchTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Now that you've got the view model just populate it:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MngBranch()
{
    DbModel pdb = new DbModel();
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.BranchTypes = new SelectList(pdb.branchtypes, "Id", "Type");
    model.CompanyNames = new SelectList(pdb.companies, "IdCompany", "CompanyName");
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult MngBranch(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("BranchSaved");
    }
    else
    {
        DbModel pdb = new DbModel();
        // You need to repopulate the drop down box values
        // if you are going to redisplay the same view
        model.BranchTypes = new SelectList(pdb.branchtypes, "Id", "Type");
        model.CompanyNames = new SelectList(pdb.companies, "IdCompany", "CompanyName");
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and now all that's left is to ensure that your view is strongly typed to this view model (rather than your domain model):

```
@model MyViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p>
        Company Name: 
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.CompanyName, Model.CompanyNames, "Choose an option")
    </p>
    <p>
        Branch Name: 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BranchName)
    </p>
    <p>
        Branch Code: 
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BranchCode)
    </p>
    <p>
        Branch Type:
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BranchType, Model.BranchTypes, "Choose an option")
    </p>
}
```

As you can see it's much easier to work with view models in ASP.NET MVC.